# sql add rows based on column values

Tags: sql

In sql, I have a table that looks like this:

| Status | Days |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 7 |

And would like to create a table like this:

| Status | Days |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| C | 7 |
| Null | 8 |
| Null | 9 |
| Null | 10 |

Note the column Days stop at 10 as it should be a predefined value.

Comment: Is this just a once-off operation? You can use an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement to insert values based upon what you select, but I don't believe you can use that to insert an arbitrarily sized range down to zero.

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: What are the rules ? .. Why 8 - 10 are Null ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but you can use a query like this

```
WITH d(days) AS (
     SELECT 0
     UNION ALL
     SELECT days+1 FROM d WHERE days < 10
)
, cte AS (
    SELECT 
        status,
        days,
        LEAD(days) OVER (ORDER BY status) AS lead_days
    FROM data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT status, days + 1, lead_days FROM cte WHERE days + 1 < lead_days
)
SELECT status, d.days INTO new_table FROM cte
RIGHT JOIN d ON d.days = cte.days
ORDER BY days
```

Please, check a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9185f6d0f303193f1b064439ebd36da7)

Comment: Got something similar on postgresql : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/5359

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of Alexey's recursive solution

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        status,
        days,
        LEAD(days, 1, 11) OVER (ORDER BY status) AS lead_days
    FROM data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT case lead_days when 11 then null else status end status, days + 1, lead_days 
    FROM cte 
    WHERE days + 1 < lead_days
)
SELECT status, days
FROM cte
ORDER BY days
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but Alexey was faster and that is why I marked his response. I suggest updating Alexey response with your simplified query.